# Resources$NotFoundException when setting up a RecyclerView in Android Studio

Tags: android

The error I occur is as below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.yangyuanhao.hw2, PID: 31877
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:215)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2134)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
                  at com.example.yangyuanhao.hw2.myViewHolder.get(myViewHolder.java:21)
                  at com.example.yangyuanhao.hw2.MyRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:62)
                  at com.example.yangyuanhao.hw2.MyRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:11)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1609)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:683)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:605)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have searched such errors, and many people say it's due to wrong use of TextView.setText method. However, I believe I pass string but int in setText function. Now, I have no idea where the problem is.

The following is my own viewholder code. Resource Not Found error happens in get method in myViewHolder class.

```
public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
private final View view;
private final SparseArray<View> views;


public myViewHolder(Context parameter, View paramView, ViewGroup paramGroup)
{
    super(paramView);
    this.view = paramView;
    this.views = new SparseArray<>();
}

public static myViewHolder get(Context _context, ViewGroup _viewGroup, int _layoutId) {
    View _view = LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(_layoutId, _viewGroup, false);
    myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(_context, _view, _viewGroup);
    return holder;
}

public <T extends View> T getView(int _viewId) {
    View _view = views.get(_viewId);
    if (_view == null) {
        // 创建view
        _view = view.findViewById(_viewId);
        // 将view存入views
        views.put(_viewId, _view);
    }
    return (T)_view;
}
```

}

And the following is my recyclerviewadapter code

```
public abstract class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myViewHolder>{

private int id;
private  List<Collection> data ;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onClick(int position);
    void onLongClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener _onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = _onItemClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context param, int id, List<Collection> mylist)
{
    this.context = param;
    this.id = id;
    this.data = mylist;
    this.data.add(new Collection("大豆", "粮", "粮食", "蛋白质", "#BB4C3B", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("十字花科蔬菜", "蔬", "蔬菜", "维生素C", "#c48d30", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("牛奶", "饮", "饮品", "钙", "#4469b0", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("海鱼", "肉", "肉食", "蛋白质", "#20A17B", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("菌菇类", "蔬", "蔬菜", "微量元素", "#BB4C3B", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("绿茶", "饮", "饮品", "无机矿质元素", "#c48d30", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("番茄", "蔬", "蔬菜", "番茄红素", "#4469b0", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("胡萝卜", "蔬", "蔬菜", "胡萝卜素", "#20A17B", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("荞麦", "粮", "粮食", "膳食纤维", "#BB4C3B", 0));
    this.data.add(new Collection("鸡蛋", "杂", "杂", "几乎所有营养物质", "#c48d30", 0));
}

public abstract void convert(myViewHolder holder, Collection param);

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return this.data.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myViewHolder holder, int id)
{
    convert(holder,this.data.get(id));
}


@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    myViewHolder holder = myViewHolder.get(context, parent, viewType);

    return holder;
}
```

Moreover, when instantiate recyclerviewadapter, I will add convert method, like below.

```
 MyRecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter =  new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, this.storeData) {
        @Override
        public void convert(myViewHolder holder, Collection s) {

            TextView name = (TextView)holder.getView(R.id.recipeName);
            name.setText(s.getName().toString());
            Button first = (Button) holder.getView(R.id.img);
            first.setText(s.getFirstChar().toString());
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance if anyone could help.

Comment: What is `_layoutId`?

Comment: The integer you used in findViewById for `_layoutId` seems cause the issue. It should not be an integer actually. it should refer to the layout at that point. I mean, it can't take an integer like (5) value. Instead, use `R.layout.yourlayout`.

Comment: Suppose, that the problem is in `myViewHolder.get(context, parent, viewType)`. If you don't override `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)` and return particular layoutId from it, you will need to do `myViewHolder.get(context, parent, id)` to fix problem (`id` - layoutId saved in constructor of  `MyRecyclerViewAdapter`)